# Smallest number of coins to guarantee exact change?

Tags: diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

> What is the smallest number of coins (excluding 50 cent piece) thats value can sum to any amount
>    .01 to .99?

This is a question that I came up with today and my immediate thought is 3Q, 2D, 1N, 4P.

My thought are, how do you justify such a thing? Are there more than one solution?

Comment: I suppose one thought I had was to assume you had less than ten coins and show that for any 9 coin pick there was a value that couldn't be made but I was hoping to get a more mathematical less brute force method

Comment: Can you say the different types of coins?

Comment: penny, nickel, dime, quarter. I did some browsing and this was also on math overflow but the answers were confirmed using algorithms to check all possible answers, I was hoping to verify it using a more mathematical method.

Comment: I meant the value of each coins.

Comment: a penny is worth one cent, a nickel is worth five cents, a dime is worth ten cents and a quarter is worth 25 cents.

Comment: I think your answer is right.

Comment: As I said in my post, my comment above, and my response to whorton; what I am looking for is some method of rigorously proving the result within our axiomatic framework. Not speculating or brute force.

Comment: You can replace one dime by another nickel. In this way you can do with a .99 total.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin narrowing it down with this: no amount can ever be further than 4 from the nearest X5 or X0. What does this mean? The answer is automatically at most, for .99, 10 dimes and a nickel and 4 pennies which would be 15. And you can subtract one from this answer for each digit below 9 for the tens place in .99...but let's consider the impact of quarters. For .99, this would be 3 quarters, 2 dimes, and 4 pennies...an answer of 9. What we see now, is that any other significant scenario (i.e. 94, 89, 69, 64, etc.) is in some way analogous to the case of .99 and results either in the same number of coins or fewer (i.e. with .94 just replace one of the dimes in .99 with a nickel and you get the same result of nine coins; and with .84 or .89 just remove a dime from .94 and .99 respectively and both answers yield results of eight coins). >Thus the answer is nine.

Comment: I don't exactly follow your logic and I actually just googled the question and multiple sites claim the ten coins I name is the correct answer, however they don't justify it. So unless you can provide me with the list of 9 coins that can make any change value I think this is blatantly wrong.

Comment: Well, if that's the question you want to ask then the answer must be ten, because as I mentioned, in order to make .94 you'd need a nickel in place of the dime in .99, meaning you'd need nine coins for .99 and an extra nickel; and every other number is just a removal of some coin or coins from either .94 or .99

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about.